# Отображение результатов перехода по ссылке в том же окне

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на странице http://site1/models/lada/#:3 реализовано то, что при клике вверху на одну из крутящихся машинок, её фотографии открываются в том же окне?

Comment: еще совет, 4ре вопроса задано и ни одного не принято, это плохо для кармы, в последствии на вопросы отвечать никто не будет.

Comment: извините, я об этом не знала, в комментариях всегда пишу, какой ответ оказался верным

Comment: а как принять ответ?

Comment: [Как принять ответ?](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading10)
@Mariya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блин, main.js, строка 89

```
if($('.cars > ul > li > a').length){
   $('.cars > ul > li').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.cars > ul > li > a').removeClass('car-active');
      $(this).addClass('car-active');
      $('#models-content-details').load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
          liveDetails();
      });
   });
}
else{
   $('.cars').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('.cars a').removeClass('car-active');
       $(this).addClass('car-active');
       $('#models-content-details').load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
           liveDetails();
       });
   });
}
```

Это ищется за 30 секунд вместе с открытием сайта

Comment: честно, код ужасен

Comment: Дык а я-то тут причём? :)  Это код с того сайта, который указан в вопросе :)

Comment: я тоже не в курсе при чём здесь вы

Comment: Photon, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Грубый вариант на js:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
    <li rel="tab3">Don't click!</li>
</ul>
<p class="tab" id="tab1">I'm tab 1</p>
<p class="tab" id="tab2">I'm tab 2</p>
<p class="tab" id="tab3">I've said: don't click!</p>

<script>
var tabs = document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName('li'), curtab = 'tab1';
document.getElementById(curtab).style.display = 'block';
for(var i = 0, il = tabs.length; i < il; ++i){
    tabs[i].onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById(curtab).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('rel')).style.display = 'block';
        curtab = this.getAttribute('rel');
    };
}
</script>

<style>
.tab{display:none}
</style>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я в вопросе имела ввиду реализацию такого мезханизма переключения именно на этом сайте, как это сделать своими способами я знаю, но мне надо подправить тот мехнизм, а я там не вижу нивызова функций JS, вобщем, не могу понять, как там сделано переключение.

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/docs/tabs/) - один из вариантов.

> По умолчанию виджет будет переключаться между вкладками разделов по событию OnClick, но событие может быть изменено в onHover через опцию. Содержимое вкладки может быть загружено с помощью Ajax, через установку HREF на вкладке.

Comment: не пойму, где прописано это событие OnClick